# how to get the class of generic?

Tags: java

I'm reading the source code about spring, and want to know the class of return value that is generic, What should I do?

```
public static <T> T getBean(String name) {
    assertContextInjected();
    System.out.println();
    return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
}
```

Comment: because  applicationContext.getBean(name) cast to T will throw a castException, and I want to know the class of T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Java the short answer is that you can't.  You can consider Generics as basically just a compile-time feature to ensure correct handling.  However, the compiled bytecode discards all the type information in a process called "Type Erasure", so effectively what the JVM gets at runtime is simply :

```
public static Object getBean(String name) {
```

However, none of that is the root cause of your problem, which is to do with your call.  I assume you have something like :

```
SomeClass someVariable = getBean("someName");
```

What's happening is that the bean that you have requested is not of type SomeClass (and casting is not going to help you with that) - So what you need to do is figure out what class the bean is that Spring is giving you, and then change the "SomeClass" in the caller to expect that type.